# Fastest way to search through text on local computer and on local website?

Tags: search, full-text-search

There is a text file with 1,000,000 lines of code floating around and Ctrl+F isn't doing the job... What are my alternatives for quickly searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Linux**

cat **code.txt** | grep -on "**pattern**"

Used python to generate a file with 1,000,000 lines, each containing a random 70 characters long string.

Then search for the pattern **ABC**, there were **3175** matches. It took 2.6 secs